# ZedGraph about YAxis and XAxis

Tags: .net, vb.net, zedgraph

I have this database:

```
hora type time and temperatura type varchar, so
hora:                temperatura:
11:47:14             +031.52
11:47:15             +033.43
11:47:16             +035.24
11:47:17             +038.50
```

I want to graph it, XAxis=hora and YAxis=temperatura
what kind of date should be 'X' and 'Y' to it work???

I did this:

```
        Dim y As Single
        Dim x As Single
```

and convert each row:

```
y = Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetString(2))
str = Replace(reader.GetString(11), ":", ".")
x = Convert.ToSingle(str)
```

but this don't work so good, look at this photo:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjKwQ.jpg)
[graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZxQz.jpg)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the data as plain text, so that people can copy&paste and give it a try? I doubt that people will re-type your data. See [ask].

Comment: Robert, ready, i edited..... sorry mi english, i not speak it.